# How can Official Game Guides be available for sale at game release dates?

Tags: technical-issues

I often search through amazon for new games. When doing this, i always wonder when i see a Official Game Guide book, which is available at release date of the game.

To write such a book, you will need to have a very early access to the game and information long before release date. So, I wonder, are these books written by the developers or someone at their company? Is this common behaviour to already write and produce a complete guide parallel to the development? Or is this done by a third party, and how to they get all the Information they need to write such a guide?

So, question is, **who makes these guides, and how are they made?**

An example would be the [Fallout 4 Vault Dweller's Survival Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0744016312) which is available on 10th Nov; same day as the game release.

> Every guide features in-depth content, detailed screen captures, quick-reference tips, and professional strategy
>
> Hardcover: 448 pages

IMO, so many details can be not provided by only playing a beta or pre-release version...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about game guides and their creation.  We are not experts in anything about game guides; they provide the same information we do, but that doesn't mean we have anything approaching expert knowledge about them.

Comment: I voted for reopen. We may not have any spesifics to go by, but there are plenty of clear patterns and industry standards that we don't need to be direcly involved to know. This question requires no inside knowledge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple, they're the official guides, they're officially supported by the game developers and can get inside information that way.

A company (the Fallout 4 guide was made by [Prima Games](http://www.primagames.com/)) is hired or asks to make the guide, and is then given a lot of information to do so.

448 pages with screenshots, listings of data, etc is not that hard to pull off.